# How to manage setNumber or setSubText method of Notification in Android Nougat

Tags: android, notifications, android-7.0-nougat

As [android google blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/notifications-in-android-n.html) clearly mentioned that Android Nougat is not supporting `setNumber` and `setContentInfo` at all and even I have tested it on Android Nougat.

Line from Google blog:

> In addition, the subtext now supersedes the role of content info and
>   number

So when I use `setNumber` for devices prior than Nougat and `setSubText` for Nougat then Nougat works perfectly only `setSubText` method works. But when I run it on Devices running prior versions they run both methods as `setNumber` and `setSubText`.

1. So how I can handle this?
2. Why android prefer `setSubText`?

In addition what is the difference between `setNumber` and `setContentInfo` ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. So how I can handle this?

Your desired result is to have your notification display whatever you pass to `setSubText()` on Nougat and above and whatever you pass to `setNumber()` on Marshmallow and below. You can accomplish this by checking the `Build` info at runtime:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    // your setSubText() code here
} else  {
    // your setNumber() code here
}
```

> 2. Why android prefer `setSubText`?

I can only really quote the blog post you linked here. They say:

"Many of the fields that were spread around the notifications have been collapsed into a new header row with your app’s icon and name anchoring the notification."

It sounds to me like a design-based preference.

> In addition what is the difference between `setNumber` and `setContentInfo` ?

[Documentation for `setContentInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentInfo(java.lang.CharSequence)): "Set the large text at the right-hand side of the notification."

[Documentation for `setNumber()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setNumber(int)): "Set the large number at the right-hand side of the notification. **This is equivalent to setContentInfo, although it might show the number in a different font size for readability.**" (emphasis added)

Comment: The if condition you use for build version check is official way?